Error launching browser in Pyppeteer on Windows
I'm working on a Python script that utilizes Pyppeteer for web scraping. However, when trying to launch the browser using the launch() function, I encounter the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\tahaa\Desktop\Jobscraper_tech\aut.py", line 49, in <module>
    asyncio.run(scrape_indeed())
  ...
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Here's the relevant code snippet:
browser = await launch(executablePath=r'"C:\Users\tahaa\Downloads\chrome-win\chrome-win"', headless=False)

I've ensured that the path to the Chrome executable is correct. However, I'm still encountering this error. How can I resolve this issue and successfully launch the browser?
Additional Information:
Operating System: Windows
Python Version: 3.10
Pyppeteer Version: 2.0.0
Chrome Version: Chromium (Chrome) Version: 1181205
